# react three fiber gsap transition menu

Tags: three.js, gsap, raycasting, react-three-fiber

Im using R3F + GSAP for animating box position. Using Raycaster I set a white box object to indicate when a menu item (box) collides with it so the animation would start.

I would like to achieve the position x to reset once the object is outside the intersection object.

Currently each menu item get positioned x = 1 when intersecting, suppose to, but occurring with a bug (see sandbox demo).

Bonus point would be to set opacity 0.5 to all menu items which are not intersecting.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scrolling-animation-rcj9pc

Three.js Rocks!
Appreciate the help :-)